# Why can't a Num be compared to 0?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

This function is incorrect and won't compile:

```
checkIsZero :: (Num a) => a -> String
checkIsZero a = if a == 0
                  then "Zero"
                  else "Not zero"
```

This doesn't work because of the comparison between a `Num` and `0` in the expression `a == 0`. Changing `Num` to `Integral` makes this a valid function.

What is this wicked sorcery that doesn't let me compare my numbers to `0`?!

Comment: in ghci it seems to work for Num; are you using ghc? what is the error message?

Comment: I put the above function into `functions.hs` then do `:l functions.hs` in `ghci` and get the error `Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from a use of '=='`

Comment: @jev Since GHC 7.4, it shouldn't work, at least not with that type signature. `Eq` is no longer implied by `Num`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Num` requires instances to implement `+`, `*`, `abs`, `signum`, and `fromInteger`.  Note that `==` isn't on the list!  It's instances of the `Eq` typeclass that must implement `==`.

So, the `Num` constraint is not sufficient - you need an `Eq` constraint too.  The following will compile.

```
checkIsZero :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> String
checkIsZero a | a == 0    = "Zero"
              | otherwise = "Not zero"
```

`Integral` works because something which is an instance of `Integral` must itself be an instance of `Ord`, which in turn must be an instance of `Eq`.

You can check all this stuff by using [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and digging into the source.

Comment: Quick comment - I think the `Integral` class is another example of Haskell's numeric type classes being broken. The notion it tries to capture is "operations that can be divided with remainder". In mathematics we call that a 'Euclidean domain' and it includes objects like the gaussian integers, polynomial rings and power series, which don't necessarily have a sensible `Ord` instance and don't admit an embedding into the integers (as is required by `toInteger`). I'd rather see a `EuclideanDomain` class and a separate `Integral` class that could encompass e.g. integers Z, and Z/pZ for p prime.

Comment: Eq is instantiated indirectly through Num for type a, since the type class Num requires Eq for type a.  It is therefore superfluous to specify Eq in the type-context

Answer (score 10):

The reason for not requiring an `Eq` instance to define a `Num` instance is that it would rule out useful instances like

```
instance Num b => Num (a -> b) where
    f + g    = \x -> f x + g x
    f - g    = \x -> f x - g x
    f * x    = \x -> f x * g x
    abs f    = \x -> abs (f x)
    signum f = \x -> signum (f x)
    fromInteger = const . fromInteger
```

because you can't write an `Eq` instance for a function.

Comment: This applies not only to such function instances but also to symbolic algebra types, infinite-precision reals, automatic-derivative types...

Comment: I think some people would argue with your description of the given instance as "useful"!

Comment: @BenMillwood I'd say those people are not imaginative enough. For an example use case, see [this paper](http://conal.net/papers/beautiful-differentiation/beautiful-differentiation.pdf) which details a simple way to implement Automatic Differentiation in Haskell, which includes lines like `cos = cos >< negate sin` (derivative of cos(x) is -sin(x)) and `log = log >< recip` (derivative of log(x) is the reciprocal of x).

Comment: @BenMillwood - Mathematicians have been using this very notation for hundreds of years. It only looks weird in Haskell since we mistakenly created a typeclass called `Num` instead of ones called `LinearSpace`, `Field`, `Algebra`, and so on.

Comment: @Fixnum: I know what mathematicians do, this does not make it a good idea :) I say this as a recent maths graduate: I love mathematics, but it's often poorly-typed and only parseable by a human with intelligence, intuition, and understanding of the concepts in play. Your instance makes it easy to write statements that look like they mean one thing but mean another, or type check when they are clearly an error. Consider `2 (x + y) = 2`. I'm aware that you can add functions, but to use `+` to refer to addition of numbers and functions simultaneously in the same context is just bad practice.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: `log = log >< recip` does not use the instance in question; your other example could just as well be `cos >< negate . sin`, and I think is actually clearer that way. AD is still beautiful without this style.

Answer (score 0):

If data is an instance of `Num a`, it is not a grantee , that this data is an instance of `Eq a`.

`Integer` (and `Int`, `Double`) has both instances: `instance Num Integer` and `instance Eq Integer`, and program is valid

`Integral` is defined as

```
class (Real a, Enum a)=> Integral a where ...
class (Num a, Ord a)=> Real a where ...
class Eq a => Ord a where ...

 ~= class (Num a, Eq a, Enum a)=> Integral a where ... --means
```

Comment: My `ghci` says that `Ord` not `Eq` is a superclass of `Real`.