# Could not deduce (Eq a) from (Num a) or from (Floating a). But Can deduce (Eq a) from (Integral a). Why?

Tags: haskell

I'm going through a haskell tutorial (Learn you a haskell for great good) and I was playing around with this code I wrote based of off one of the functions in the book.

```
reverseNum :: (Num a) => a -> a
reverseNum 123 = 321
reverseNum x = 0
```

and ghci tells me that it can't deduce (Eq a) from (Num a).

So I change the first line to this

```
reverseNum :: (Integral a) => a -> a
```

and it worked. This was strange because I thought to be a part of the Num typeclass you needed to also be apart of Eq.

I tried one more thing to satisfy me curiosity and changed the first 2 lines to this

```
reverseNum :: (Floating a) => a -> a
reverseNum 1.0 = 0.1
```

and it gave me the same error.

I know that you can fix this by doing something like `reverseNum :: (Num a, Eq a) ...` but I want to know why Integral is the only one where Eq can be deduced.
Why is that?

P.S. I am really new to haskell so... be gentle :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't a Num be compared to 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623876/why-cant-a-num-be-compared-to-0)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Short answer

Because that's the definition of `Num` in the prelude:

```
class Num a where
    ...
```

Whereas the definition for `Integral` requires the type to be `Real` and `Enum`:

```
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
    ...
```

And `Real` implies both `Num` and `Ord`...

```
class (Num a, Ord a) => Real a where
    ...
```

And `Ord`, naturally, implies `Eq`:

```
class Eq a => Ord a where
    ...
```

This line means that in order to make something implement `Ord`, it **must** also implement `Eq`.  Or we could say that `Ord` is a subclass of `Eq`.  Anyway...

The summary is that `Num` is not a subclass of `Eq`, but `Integral` is a subclass of `Eq`.

### Long answer (why?)

You can imagine implementing `Num` in ways that make it impossible to implement `Eq`.

```
newtype Sequence = Sequence (Integer -> Integer)

instance Num Sequence where
  (Sequence x) + (Sequence y) = Sequence $ \pt -> x pt + y pt
  (Sequence x) - (Sequence y) = Sequence $ \pt -> x pt - y pt
  (Sequence x) * (Sequence y) = Sequence $ \pt -> x pt * y pt
  negate (Sequence x) = Sequence $ \pt -> -pt
  abs (Sequence x) = Sequence $ \pt -> abs pt
  signum (Sequence x) = Sequence $ \pt -> signum pt
  fromInteger = Sequence . const

-- Ignore the fact that you'd implement these methods using Applicative.
```

Here, `Sequence` is the type representing all computable sequences.  You can't implement `Eq` in any reasonable way, because the sequences are infinitely long!

```
instance Eq Sequence where
  -- This will never return True, ever.
  (Sequence x) == (Sequence y) =
      and [x pt == y pt | pt <- [0..]] &&
      and [x pt == y pt | pt <- [-1,-2..]]
```

So it makes sense that `Num` is not a subclass of `Eq`, because there are *useful* types which can implement `Num` but not `Eq`.

Comment: Beat me to the answer, and yours was a lot better worded.  Have an upvote.

Comment: It's important to add that this is *not* the definition of `Num` in the Haskell 2010 Prelude; this is just what GHC does.  In Haskell 2010, `Num a` implies both `Eq a` and `Show a`.

Comment: Wait... then why doesn't Int have Eq? Isn't int a subtype of Integral?

Comment: @thecodethinker: `Int` is a type, which implements `Eq`, which is a class.  So `Int` does have `Eq`.

Comment: Okay... I guess I'm just messing up somewhere. Thanks