# Haskell: Does Num class "inherit" Eq class?

Tags: haskell

From Learn You a Haskell, I have:

```
lucky :: Integral a => a -> String
lucky 7 = "lucky number seven!"
lucky x = "try again"
```

but, when I do

```
lucky :: Num a => a -> String
lucky 7 = "lucky number seven!"
lucky x = "try again"
```

I get

```
Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from literal `7'
```

So, then I do

```
lucky :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> String
lucky 7 = "lucky number seven!"
lucky x = "try again"
```

and, the compiler is happy.

Doesn't the Num type class "inherit" the Eq class?

Saying (Num a, Eq a) seems redundant.  From the Haskell 98 report, where they have a great diagram (yeah, visuals!) of the Standard Classes it sure seems like it's "inherited." http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Haskell report suggests that `Num` should be a subclass of `Eq` and `Show`, but if you look at [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Num.html#Num) for the `Num` class in ghc, then it is not.

This change appears to have been introduced in [GHC 7.4.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/release-7-4-1.html)

Comment: Why was this decision taken? Is there some representation of some kind of numbers where a default Equality constraint cannot be imposed?

Comment: @kishlaya I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18676613/8234626 . Short version is that there are objects (e.g. infinite sequences) for which `Eq` may not be implemented in finite time while the rest of the `Num` methods may be. Real numbers can be represented as equivalence classes of cauchy sequences of rational numbers, so that is an example where `Eq` may be unable to be sensibly implemented.

Comment: instance Num a => Num (x -> a) was blocked by having Eq (and to a lesser extent, Num) as a superclass. 

The fact that lots of folks wanted to use this instance and otherwise had to lie and claim you could compare functions was what ultimately let to Ian removing both the Eq and Show superclass constraints from Num in GHC, despite it being a break with Haskell 98, but it isn't the only example, by far.

Comment: "lots of folks" I don't believe. Presumably it was actually the same headstrong few people who inflicted the FTP change on sensible Haskellers. What's worst about these hooligans is that there's no way to opt out of these changes in GHC, to arrive at a standards-compliant version of the language for teaching purposes (and for avoiding weird type messages, as in this q).